# unixtimestamp input in DataTimeField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Per specification I have date and time input in `UnixTimeStamp` Also, I need check that I have only digits on input (nor something like this "2011-12-12")
I have `forms.DataTimeField` and `model.DataTimeField` now.

I decided to modify this in such way:
Added `UnixTimeStampField(forms.RegexField)` - here I check with regular expression, that I have only digits.

But I got problem with model, since `UnixTimeStampField(forms.RegexField)` is based on string and need to be converted to datatime.
I don't like this solution.

How I can create something like `UnixTimeStampField(forms.DateTimeField)`?
I tried to do this, but then I have "123321" on input I got "Incorrect parameter" from `DateTimeField` validators.

Comment: is this a model field or a form field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a custom model and/or form field for this. Just use the built-in `forms.DateTimeField` and `models.DateTimeField`, then add the following settings to your `settings.py`:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = "U"
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ("%s",)
```

Read more about this settings [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#datetime-format).

Comment: How can I do this for just one of my forms and not as a global setting?

Comment: You could override the field you are using for the date and specify which format the field will accept. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L395