# Django - in the model, created_at is a UNIX timestamp

Tags: python, django, unix

I am new to Django. I would have better grasp of this in Rails but am not familiar enough with all the libraries and converstions in Python / Django.

I have a model:

```
class Status(models.Model):
  created = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This results in the format:

```
"created": "2017-01-06T22:21:51.531723Z"
```

I was hoping to see if before saving to the DB that it stores as a UNIX value?

This looked promising https://stackoverflow.com/a/34843855/3007294 but can't get it working. Every time I try to create a Status object, I get this error:

```
Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z].
```

My intentions are to not have to enter this every time a Status object is created.

Thanks -

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The field will be saved as the database's datetime format. You don't have to do anything at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was hoping to save the field as a UNIX timestamp (converted from the datetime format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My intentions are to not have to enter this every time a Status object is created.

This is already taken care of with the [`auto_now_add=True` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add). When you create a `Status` object, the `created` field will be populated with the current datetime.

> I was hoping to see if before saving to the DB that it stores as a UNIX value?

You can convert the `datetime` value from `Status.created` to a Unix timestamp anytime required. Storing it in the default database datetime format (which is what `DatetimeField` does) is generally preferred to storing it as a timestamp, which is just an integer.

However, the library used in the example you provided, [`django-unixdatetimefield`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-unixdatetimefield/), states that "UnixDateTimeField is based on the implementation of the standard Django DateTimeField, making it 100% compatible with all features and options it supports." So, you should be able to provide the `auto_now_add=True` option to that field.

Comment: Thanks @Rushy for clarifying! I didn't review the docs well enough and you were right. Appreciate it!