# Storing unix timestamp as an IntegerField

Tags: django, datetime, unix-timestamp

Is it a bad idea to store a unix time stamp as an integer and simply convert it to datetime when needed in Django ?

I found the `UnixDateTimeField` field from the django-unixdatetimefield package, but I don't see the benefit.  You can also override the `pre_save` method on the `DateTimeField` but it adds unecssary complexity.

the above mentioned methods are found at this link: [django - make datetimefield accept unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178637/django-make-datetimefield-accept-unix-timestamp)

Comment: the only limitation is that the unix timestamp can be stored till 2038 ?

Comment: *unix timestamp* is not "human-readable", which require a *conversion* to DateTime if you wish to show the value somewhere.

Comment: yes, in python that is simple `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`

Comment: Yes. IMHO, it is not about "simple" or "complex", it is about *"is it 'really required'" or not*

Comment: thats the question I have.  Is it really required that I install a new package when I can simply use an int field and convert when needed.

Comment: Depends on your *use-case*. I hope the question *"Which kind of data do you need the most time, timestamp? or datetime?"* will answer that